# rails3-jquery-autocomplete and mongomapper gives NoMethodError undefined method `table_name`

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, mongomapper

i'm trying to get autocomplete working with [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) . i have my rails app using mongomapper and have the following model:

```
class Port
  include MongoMapper::Document
  set_collection_name "ports__status"
  key :device, String
```

in my controller i have

```
class PortsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :port, :device
```

any my routes is:

```
resources :ports do
  get :autocomplete_port_device, :on :collection
end
```

so, in my view i have

```
<form class="uri_replace" method="get" action="/ports/%device%/">
  <input class="inline_replace" name="device" data-autocomplete="/ports/autocomplete_port_device"></input>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

(i have a rewrite on the `action` to submit the input value for a more 'restful' query interface)

so i load up the page, and i can see ajax requests after i type stuff into the form... however, i get the following error:

```
NoMethodError in PortsController#autocomplete_port_device

  undefined method `table_name' for Port:Class
```

any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rails3-jquery-autocomplete` gem can work with MongoDB, but only if you use the `mongoid` gem, **not** `mongomapper`.

Reference: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete#mongoid